# how can we use multiple Kendo library version in the same project

Tags: kendo-ui

There is a requirement in which some of the module is developed in Kendo with jQuery and others are developed in Kendo with Angular 4, in the same project.

How can we fix this multiple kendo version environment in the single project.

Comment: Why do you need different Kendo UI version? Cant you make use of a wrapper to access the jQuery methods with the same Kendo UI version?

Comment: You are right. But the module is developed couples of year before using   jQuey + Kendo. In the current development we are using Angular+Kendo. 

Therefor both Kendo library having different version. Once it is deployed previous (i.e. jQuery + Kendo) module stop working, as it is not getting the reference for kendo library. It is override by new kendo(Angular + Kendo).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

url : URL to Load the library file(different version file), on which our module is dependent, and in side function block, write all codes.

```
    $.getScript("url ", function (a) {
        ........
    });
```

This help me to resolve the issue, and all modules are working fine.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of integrating Kendo UI for jQuery in an Angular project:

[Docs + Example](https://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/framework/kendo-jquery/)

Comment: Thanks for the update.  But that is not the solution i was looking for.
Just consider:   we have one legacy product in which there are many modules, which are developed in different technologies, like .net, jQuery+Kendo, Angular+Kendo, and XSLT.  

Once it is deployed together, it was working fine until did not add new module developed in Angular+Kendo. As there is already a module is developed in jQuery+Kendo previously, it(Kendo library) was getting override by new modules(i.e. Angular + Kendo). 

Due to that, the older module stop working, as it was not getting reference .